# Why wasn't this text written in the simple past?

Tags: past-tense, past-simple, used-to

If the following verbs in bold talk about actions in the past, why we don't use the simple past instead?

> Tom and Della were a young married couple. Every morning Tom **used to
>   kiss** Della and **set off** for work. Della **used to stand** at the window and **wave** good-bye. In the evening she **used to welcome**
>   him home and **ask** him to tell her about his day.

For instance:

> Every morning Tom **kissed** Della and **set off** for work. Delia **stood** at the window and **waved** good-bye

Comment: You have the verb **used to** which tells us that the  actions were habitual in the past. The verbs that come *after* are in the infinitive tense.

Comment: related: [**Used to or past simple?**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47542/used-to-or-past-simple), [**Correct use of “used to”**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100485/correct-use-of-used-to) and [**I used to study at Cambridge School**](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23682/i-used-to-study-at-cambridge-school)

Comment: However, if you also ask "why" the simple past tense is not used, the question becomes quite interesting (to me at least). Would you mind if I edited your question?

Comment: I don't mind :)

Comment: You can of course make further edits, or change things back, but I think this questions stands a decent chance of survival and might attract a few (more than some) visits.

Comment: I don't think the question can be fully answered without delving into narrative style, which is sort of off-limits here on ELL. Suffice to say that *used to* emphasizes that an action was habitual in the past, with the implication that it no longer occurs.

Comment: As a matter of personal style, I think replacing "used to" by "would" works better here: "Every morning Tom would kiss Della... Della would stand at the window....".

Answer (score 1):

There is a subtle difference, the meaning is similar either way.

"Every morning Tom used to kiss Della..." suggests he doesn't any more, that this was in the past, removed from now.

On the other hand, "Every morning Tom kissed Della..." may be the story of their lives right now, today.

I can explain this as a native speaker, I'm not good with formal grammatical terms though. Hope this helps.